# How to add data in a many-to-many relation in Django?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am struggling with the many-to-many relationships. My models are :

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    carmodel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    modelno = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Owner(models.Model):
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(maxx_length=30)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

I want to be able to add Data in the `Owner` model. Their are already some existing `carmodel` and `modelno` data in the `Cars`.

The user is supplying a list of carmodels, choosing from the existing available list and then `name` `car_id` `address` and `contact`. How do I add this data into Owner model?

Edit : Removed the field car_id from Owner. It is not required at the moment in my model.

Comment: That's actually a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Why do you have both `car` and `car_id` on the `Owner` model? Are they supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: sorry its a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Django will create 3 tables (car, owner, car_owner). If you want add data to owner, just add normall to owner. If you want to add cars to owner, just modify car field of that owner (better to name it cars, if this is many to many)

Comment: @Krab Sorry I dont really get it. if I want to add 3 cars to a one object of Owner, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta: owner.cars.add(car)

Comment: @Krab Oh that was simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)!

In above django document replace `class Publication` from `class Cars`
and `class Article` with `class Owner` and follow the steps .. simple .. 
Hope it helps ..

Comment: no it's many-to-many. I can have more than one type of car (for instance ford mondeo and ford fiesta), and one car (ford fiesta) can have many ppls.